# Unable Parse a JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, mongo-jackson-mapper

I have a mongo database call in my code. The response from the database is mapped using codehaus jackson.

Json:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "555",
    "rates": 1,
    "reviews": [
      {
        "author_name": "Instructor 9999",
        "_authKey": "demo\\556",
        "text": "asdfa",
        "date": 551,
        "_id": "5454-4920",
        "title": "asdf",
        "comments": []
      }
    ],
    "votedUsers": [
      {
        "mng\\39999": 4
      }
    ],
    "rating": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": "45589",
    "rates": 1,
    "reviews": [
      {
        "author_name": "feef",
        "_authKey": "ad\\ads",
        "text": "Working perfect",
        "date": 1498659163,
        "_id": "asdas-319",
        "title": "test",
        "comments": []
      }
    ],
    "votedUsers": [
      {
        "abc\\bis@cdf.com": 4
      }
    ],
    "rating": 4
  }
]
```

I have created the below DTO Stucture:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MaterialReviewsDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String _id;
    private int rates;
    private List<ReviewsDTO> reviews;
    private List<VotedUsersDTO> votedUsers;
    //List<TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>> votedUsers;
    private int rating;.
    //Getter Setter
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class VotedUsersDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Map<String, String> votedUser;
    //Getter Setter
}
```

Below is the code where I am firing the query:

```
List<MaterialReviewsDTO> materialReviewsDTOs = DBConnectionRealmByDBName
                    .find(query,
                            MaterialReviewsDTO.class,
                            CollectionNameConstant.REVIEWS_COLLECTION);
```

Problem is all the JSON is getting mapped in DTO except the below part:

```
"votedUsers" : [ 
            {
                "abc\\bis@cdf.com" : 4
            }
        ]
```

VotedUserDTO is null in response. VotedUsers is a list of object containg data in key-value pair.

I am not mentioning ReviewsDTO as this is getting mapped perfectly. How can I map `votedUsers` part?
**Note:** I am using Spring for development.

Comment: Updated the JSON

Comment: @talex In JSON there is `votedUsers` and in MaterialReviewsDTO there also I have mentioned `votedUsers`

Comment: Because of bad design of JSON, you end up with this issue, In JSON key should be constant and value should variable. You can change `List<Map<String, Integer>> votedUsers` and try

Comment: @dkb Thanks. Its working with your solution. Please post this as an answer so that I can mark it as a solution. :)

Comment: I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the observations from your JSON
1. Json should be designed with Fixed key and variable values in mind.
2. Since in above case both Key and values are variable, we can use Map
So final solution is
change from `private List<VotedUsersDTO> votedUsers;` to `private List<Map<String, Integer>> votedUsers`

Answer (score 0):

`private List<Map<String, String>> votedUsers;`

Do not use the explicit votedUser DTO.

Answer (score -1):

The votedUsers is expected to be a List of VotedUsersDTOs.
If you look at your VotedUsersDTO in the JSON:

```
{
"abc\\bis@cdf.com" : 4
}
```

This would imply there is a field `abc\\bis@cdf.com` where you want the value to be 4. 
This doesn't comply with `id` or `votedUser` Map in the DTO definition.

Comment: If you see in the JSON, the field `abc\\bis@cdf.com` is not constant for every document. In some document it is `abc\\bis@cdf.com`, but for another document it may be something random like `mno\\com`. So defining a field named `abc\\bis@cdf.com` in Java will not be a solution

Comment: Indeed, this is a changing value throughout your examples. But mapping to VotedUsersDTO would imply mapping to a structure with and `id` and `votedUser`. By changing the `votedUsers` to a List<Map<String, Integer>>, this is no longer the case. (as you acknowledged being the correct answer).